# Naming variable, best convention

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

What is the most used convention for naming variables in Python / Django?
ex: pub_date or pubdate

What about for classes and methods?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Django's coding style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)

Answer (score 10):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), nothing more to say.

Of course you can use your own style (I use camelCase, for example), but most people use recommendations from that PEP.

Answer (score 2):

Code Complete (http://www.cc2e.com/) has some great chapters about function/variable naming, not for Python explicitly, but perhaps still interesting...

Comment: For completeness, I guess you mean [this page](http://www.cc2e.com/chapters/id/225?hid=225).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the correct references to PEP-8 and Django, let me add Google's Python style guide, which features a naming convention. It is [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyguide.html#Naming).

Answer (score 1):

The important thing is being consistent with your naming style. Choose one with your project mates and use it. Don't mix them. I personally use camelCase:

Sample class name: MyClass (capital letter at the beginning)

Sample method name: myMethod

Sample variable name: myVariable

Sample constant/enum name: MY_CONST

Class name should start with capital letter to make clear what it is in your code. Same about constants/enums. Values that don't change throughout your program should consist of capital letters.

Comment: I'm on your side, however it's quite hard to be consistent while the rest of Python follow PEP8, it means the code written by yourself, variable name is `variableName` but if import other code, it's `variable_name`. so annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

I use `lower_case_with_underscore` for variables, methods and functions. I think it really improves readability of the code.

For classes, I tend to use upper case the first letter: `class NewsForm (forms.Form):`